# How to insert images/blobs into SQL Server CE (just like sqlite)?

Tags: image, sqlite, sql-server-ce, blob

There is a GUI for sqlite where all the image values can be inserted. Similarly is there any option available in SQL Server Management Studio to insert the images.

Any info about that will be of great purpose.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use my SQL Server Compact Toolbox (VS add-in or standalone) and right clikc the image column to import/export images. http://sqlcetoolbox.codeplex.com

Comment: Thanks a lot sir, you've been helping me in every possibility.